# How to write Sheyichye in short in english

Tags: names, acronyms

I know that in Hebrew it is written שי'‏.

How should I write it in English letters in short so that people will understand it?

Maybe she' or shi'?

Comment: Probably as when writing ב"ה we write BH you may write it 'sy as in Hebrew it is שי idk?

Comment: B"H and BS"D is a "relatively" recent invention. I began seeing this about 25 - 30 years ago. Prior to that, people just used Hebrew letters. The point being, in my opinion, most people who care and understand what the abbreviation is about will understand the Hebrew.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @DanF my problem is I can only use English characters (and I have a limited number I can use)

Comment: hazoriz, I bet if you explain the problem with which you are faced, including context and the constraints of possible solutions, you will get higher quality answers, and probably also suggestions to preempt the problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think not, but it has no closure votes, and two people commented here who can cast such.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend "(may he live!)". It's unambiguous, unlike an abbreviation, which may stand for any number of things, and unlike, especially, a transliterated abbreviation, which may represent different Hebrew abbreviations to people with different Hebrew dialects. It's also more accessible to those who don't know Hebrew, or who don't know it well. And the parentheses set it off from the running text, so that, even though it's a slightly long phrase, the reader can treat it as an aside and it doesn't break up the flow of the surrounding text.